How to use host as HAProxy calculated backend target?
I'm wanting to intercept TCP traffic then forward everything else to their respective back-end servers. I have an internal DNS with matching domain to the wildcard external ingress.
I'm thinking something like the following, but I suspect this is not supported as HAProxy verifies the backend at start and this would not resolve to anything.
server all { req.hdr(host) }:443 check ssl verify none
My full configuration follows:
# This file is managed by Puppet
global
  chroot  /var/lib/haproxy
  daemon
  group  haproxy
  log  172.22.91.180 local0
  maxconn  4000
  pidfile  /var/run/haproxy.pid
  user  haproxy

defaults
  log  global
  maxconn  8000
  option  redispatch
  retries  3
  timeout  http-request 10s
  timeout  queue 1m
  timeout  connect 10s
  timeout  client 1m
  timeout  server 1m
  timeout  check 10s

frontend waf-server
  bind 172.22.91.180:443
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  use_backend load-balancer if { req_ssl_sni -i rdg.example.com }
  default_backend reverse-proxy

backend load-balancer
  balance roundrobin
  server blue rd1.example.com:443 check
  server green rd2.example.com:443 check

backend reverse-proxy
  mode tcp
  server loopback-terminated abns@haproxy-terminate send-proxy-v2

frontend https-terminated
  mode http
  stats enable
  bind abns@haproxy-terminate accept-proxy ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/fullchain.cer
  use_backend jenkins if { req.hdr(host) -i jenkins.example.com }
  use_backend puppet if { req.hdr(host) -i puppet.example.com }

backend jenkins
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
  http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
  server jenkins jenkins.example.com:443 check ssl verify none

backend puppet
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
  http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
  server puppet puppet.example.com:443 check ssl verify none


You may want to look into this https://www.haproxy.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-haproxy

Thank you, that's quite valuable for my TCP traffic. I didn't make it clear enough in my example as to what I'm waiting to avoid. In this example, I have two (of my 45) back-end servers defined, I want to have a single definition to map incoming name to outgoing name.

In short, each back-end has to be explicitly defined. I was able to reduce the manual errors by using Puppet to generate all the back-ends I needed, a snippet follows
# In modules/haproxy/manifests/backend.pp
define waf_server::dynamic_backend (
  String $backend_name,
  String $host,
) {
  haproxy::backend { $backend_name:
    mode    => 'http',
    options => [
      { 'option'        => 'forwardfor' },
      { 'option'        => 'http-server-close' },
      { 'http-request'  => 'set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]' },
      { 'http-request'  => 'add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https' },
      { 'http-response' => 'set-header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"' },
      { 'server'        => "${backend_name} ${host}:443 check ssl verify none" },
    ],
  }
}

and in init.pp
  $backends = {
    'jenkins' => 'jenkins.example.com',
    'puppet'  => 'puppet.example.com',
  }

  $options = $backends.map |$backend, $host| {
    { 'use_backend' => "${backend} if { req.hdr(host) -i ${host} }" }
  }

  haproxy::frontend { 'https-terminated':
    mode    => 'http',
    bind    => { 'abns@haproxy-terminate' => ['accept-proxy', 'ssl', 'crt', '/etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem'] },
    options => [
      { 'option' => 'httplog' }  # enable HTTP Access logging
    ] + $backends.map |$backend, $host| {
      { 'use_backend' => "${backend} if { req.hdr(host) -i ${host} }" }
    },
      require => Haproxy::Backend[$backends.keys], # Ensure all backends are created first
  }

